# Variable to = specific parts of array

Tags: php

I have 36 check boxes... I call them with this.
Labeled like this.

```
 <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='ck[]'>
```

Called like this

```
$checks = $_POST['ck']
$vars = array(
                'ck1' => 'Demo',
                'ck2' => 'Demo2',
                'ck3' => 'Demo3',
                'ck4' => 'Demo4',
                'ck5' => 'Demo5',
                'ck6' => 'Demo6',
                'ck7' => 'Demo7',
                'ck8' => 'Demo8',
                'ck9' => 'Demo9',
                'ck10' => 'Demo10',

                );


            foreach($vars as $key=>$default) {
                $checks[$key] = !empty($checks[$key]) ? $default : '';
            }
```

How can I now make it where 2 new variables = specifics from that post.
For instance,

```
$CH1 = checks[1] - checks[6];
$ch2 = checks[6] - checks[10];
```

And then,

How can I make it where if there are numbers in `$CH1` it will list and break.. like this

```
 $checks[1] . '<br>' . $checks[2] and so on....
```

UPDATE***

```
$vars = array(
                '1' => 'Desktop',
                '2' => 'Laptop Only',
                '3' => 'Laptop / Dock',
                '4' => 'Laptop Case',
                '5' => 'Desk Phone',
                '6' => 'Monitor',
                '7' => 'Printer Access',
                '8' => 'Printer - Personal',
                '9' => 'Email(phone)',
                '10' => 'Office 365',
                '11' => 'Sharepoint',
                '12' => 'Fax Fwd',
                '13' => 'Adobe DC',
                '14' => 'Apacheta',
                '15' => 'Brightree',
                '16' => 'TeamDME',
                '17' => 'DirectView',
                '18' => 'RingCentral',
                '19' => 'Faxage',
                '20' => 'Google Docs',
                '21' => 'Badge Access',
                '22' => 'Title Plate',
                '23' => 'Bis Cards',
                '24' => 'Travel',
                '25' => 'Exp Reports',
                '26' => 'Order Pads',
                '27' => 'Demo Trilogy',
                '28' => 'Stickers',
                '29' => 'APS',
                '30' => 'CBSS',
                '31' => 'Conexis',
                '32' => 'Evenfy',
                '33' => 'Inventory',
                '34' => 'AMEX',
                '35' => 'Fuel Card',
                '36' => 'Vehicle'
                );


            foreach($vars as $key=>$default) {
                $checks[$key] = !empty($checks[$key]) ? $default : '';
            }
```

When I echo $checks, it just says array.. does not show any numbers names that were checked.

Comment: You can't echo an array, use `print_r($checks)` or `var_dump($checks)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to dinamically read the values, you can construct the key value with the name you already have:

```php
$num_a = 1;
$num_b = 6;

$CH1 = checks['ck' . $num_a] - checks['ck' . $num_b];
```

Comment: - means through I n php? I was only using that as an example

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq I just copied what you tried to do. The point is that you can build the keys of the array on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$CH1 = array_slice($checks, 0, 6);
```

Now *$CH1* will be an array with the first 6 checks only. To get the next 10 (for instance):

```
$CH2 = array_slice($checks, 6, 10);
```

...etc.

Then you can loop through them just like you would do with another array:

```
foreach($CH1 as $chk) {
    //
}
```

If you want to check if any of those is numeric, use [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php):

```
foreach($CH1 as $chk) {
    if (is_numeric($chk)) echo $chk . "<br>";
}
```

You can also *filter* an array based on a condition. Let's say you want to eliminate the empty elements from the *$checks* array:

```
$filtered = array_filter($checks, function ($chk) { return !empty($chk); });
```

... and now output that filtered array with each entry on a separate line:

```
echo implode('<br>', $filtered);
```

Finally, you can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) to get out of your *$vars* array only those elements that have been checked, as follows:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($vars, array_flip($_POST['ck']));
```

So, if the user had selected checkboxes with value 1, 5 and 10, the *$results* array will look like this:

```
array (
  1 => 'Desktop',
  5 => 'Desk Phone',
  20 => 'Google Docs',
)
```

See it on [eval.in](https://eval.in/private/8dc6325e365fbf).

I hope these ideas will all be helpful and of use to you.

Comment: When you echo an array, that is what you get. Instead, `echo implode(',', $checks);`... which will not yet be what you need, but a lot closer.

Comment: When I do that, I just got a ton of ","

Comment: That means all the elements are empty. It is normal that they are separated by commas, that is how implode works. You can change the implode character by specifying a different one as first character.... See also the addition I made to my answer.

Comment: The thing is though, there not empty... see $checks = $_POST['ck'];  if I use checks it does not work.... Yet if I use $_POST['ck'] instead, it works. is there a issue in the forreach?

Comment: You are very vague. Can you update your question with sample data, print outs of what `$_POST['ck']` contains, and exactly which output you expect to have? I will help you out, but it is not going to work if you don't bring some clarity.

Comment: I propose the use of array_intersect_key to get the selected entries out of the $vars array. See end of my answer.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq, did this answer your question? Could you give some feed-back?